# Aliasing a command with parameter supplied to another command

Tags: shell, alias, function

Namely: I want to alias `tail -f` to `less +F` but let tail with any other parameter supplied work the same way as before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is slightly beyond the powers of what shell aliases provide (assuming bash). You could define a function:

```
function tail() {
    if [ "$1" == '-f' ]; then
        shift
        less +F "$@"
     else
         command tail "$@"
     fi
 }
```

When you type `tail`, this will now refer to the function defined
above, which checks its first argument, if any, for equality with
`-f`, and if it matches, runs `less +F` on the rest of the original
arguments (`shift` removes the first of the original arguments,
`-f`). Otherwise, it calls the command `tail` with all of the original
arguments (calling the built-in `command` is necessary to avoid an
infinite loop; without it, `tail` would refer to the function being
defined, causing an infinite loop).

Comment: What does `shift` exactly do?

Comment: I just pushed an edit to answer this.

Comment: This works for `tail` but not `ls`! I'm using `function ls() { echo "Test" }` (with newlines), but ls works as normal. Whereas `function tail() { echo "Test" }` works.

Comment: @tog22: My guess would be that you have an `ls` _alias_ shadowing your `ls` function. Try `type -a ls` to find out, and possibly use `unalias` to get rid of the alias if it is not wanted.

Comment: Thanks, you got it!